# REGEX Get String If Not Contain Specific Word

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

I want to get string if the string not contain word "RAM".

> String : 
> 16/32/64 GB 
>   2 GB RAM
>  32/64 GB 
>  3 GB RAM 
>  64 GB 
>  4 GB RAM

And the result to be obtained  :

> String : 
> 16/32/64 GB 
>    32/64 GB 
>  64 GB

What the regex pattern should be used?
Please help me. Thank You.

Comment: Alternatively why not just use [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)?

Comment: What did you try and what error did you face?

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '16/32/64 GB
2 GB RAM
32/64 GB
3 GB RAM
64 GB
4 GB RAM';
$pattern = '/\d+\sGB\sRAM/';
echo preg_replace($pattern, '', $str);
```